# Combine and transform multiple data sets with different questions (column) in R

Tags: r

I have multiple datasets that I would like to combine into one. Each dataset represents different timepoint of the survey. Since it is a within-subject design, my final goal is to convert into the format like this (for SPSS data analysis):

`id pretest T1 T2 T3 posttest
 1   3       5  5  3  6
 2   3       5  5  3  6`

Now each dataset looks like this:

`date ip Q76 Q31 Q307....`

The questions involve two aspects:

step1: I need to merge multiple datasets which have different questions (column name) into one. The goal is to find their union and leave the cell blank if that question does not appear in the specific survey. I used the below code, but it seems not include every question:

`library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
merge1 <- bind_rows(pre, post)
setdiff(pre, post)
setdiff(post, pre)`

step2: After combining multiple datasets into one. I'd like to convert to the format as above for within-subject design analysis.

Any ideas on ways to accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: Post an example with data objects that can be "worked". Also post what the final answer would be for that example.

Comment: You should get all of the datasets into one `list`, and then use `rbindlist(list)` to do this task extremely quick.

To get them into one list use `list <- mget(ls(pattern = "Pattern of named dataset"))`

Comment: Please post reproducible code. Try using `dput` on your data set and posting the results.